# Is there a standard reference to learn interjections?

Tags: interjections

Such as: Ouch! Oops! Hey! Aargh! Aw man! Brrr (It's cold)!

These are examples of some things one might say in English. Some of them won't be found in the dictionary, but there are usually lists you can find online that will explain what they mean.

Here's a list of some common English interjections, as an example: https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/interjections.htm

Is there a reference like this in Esperanto?

Comment: I redirected your question to ask *how* to learn these words. Usually I'm  pretty adamant that we avoid linking to outside references as answers, but in this case, soliciting a boundless list of "vote on all the words" makes little sense in the context of this type of Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one on [Quizlet](https://quizlet.com/257604/esperanto-interjections-flash-cards/) where you can learn the interjections playfully. Not sure how useful it is, since ***! is the translation for *Fek!*.

There is another [list of interjections](http://esperanto.davidgsimpson.com/eo-interjections.html) here that certainly seems useful.

And [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Esperanto_interjections) is helpful.

None as full of explanations as your English resource, though.

Answer (score 12):

PMEG calls them *ekkriaj vortetoj* and has [a list of them](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/ekkrioj_sonimitoj/index.html).