# What are words that are the equivalent of 'ow' in English?

Tags: word-usage

This relates to onomatopoeia. Also, is there an index of words for onomatopoeia in Esperanto?

Answer (score 3):

I went through the book *Esperanto Learning and Using the International Language* and the word which the author, David Richardson, teaches for the English words ***Ouch!*** and ***Ow!*** is ***Aj!***.

Answer (score 3):

[PMEG has a list](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/ekkrioj_sonimitoj/neoficialaj_ekkrioj.html) of these words and it suggests *aj* or *aŭ* to express pain. The second one is coveniently pronounced the same as "ow" which is good because if you stub your toe at an esperanto event and instinctively say "ow" nobody will call you a crocodile :) I believe the other one is what French and Spanish people tend to say.

Also check out [this other similar question](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/275/is-there-a-standard-reference-to-learn-interjections).