# What is the interjection "aw" in Esperanto?

Tags: interjections

I'm looking for an interjection to express sympathy or dissapointment, or in response to something sweet.

I first thought of aŭ , but apppart from being a conjuction I recently learned that can be used to express pain.

Looking through the suggested sources of this question gave no result:

[Is there a standard reference to learn interjections?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/275/is-there-a-standard-reference-to-learn-interjections)

Answer (score 4):

For sympathy or disappointment, I would say *Ho ve* and then some other words of sympathy like *Mi bedaŭras aŭdi tion.*

For something cute - why not *ho! tre ĉarme!* ?

For pain *aj* is much more common.